# Voltar ao inicio em C

Tags: c

Eu criei uma calculadora em C, com menu e tudo mais, com o `switch case` ao escolher uma função entre `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc. Você digita dois valores e eles são executados de acordo com a função. Como fazer para após terminar a operação aritmética, o programa voltar ao menu principal para poder escolher novamente uma outra operação?

Comment: Coloque seu código feito até agora.

Comment: Bem vindo. Poste seu código na pergunta, fica mais fácil para o pessoal ajudar.

Comment: Pode colocar tudo em um `while` ou usar `goto`

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Coloque um while antes ou entre o código principal, onde ele espera um char(`s`/`n`), na primeira execução já inicialize uma variável(`opcao`) com com `s`, depois da operação faça a escrita de algo como `deseja efetuar mais calculos S/N?` em seguida faça a leitura com `scanf()`, após isso será feita avalição de `opcao` no while, se `s` faz outro conta do contrario encerra o programa.

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode usar `goto` e `labels:`, já que está usando C.
Exemplo:

```
inicio:
print("teste");
goto inicio;
```

Comment: Utilizar o `goto` deve ser evitado, apenas se usa quando não se consegue escrever o código de uma maneira mais legível.

Comment: Só quis demonstrar outra maneira de como pode ser feito. O uso ou não uso de labels e gotos não entra muito no mérito da pergunta dele.